# Badly placed ()'s error with the following shell script

Tags: arrays, shell, for-loop, sh

This is the code snippet.
Here i am seeing the badly placed ()'s error

```
#!/bin/sh 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# array declaration
arr= (one two three)  # seeing error here

# for loop
for (( i=0;i<4;i++ ))
do
    echo "\n $i : ${a[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Is your !# invocation correct ?

Answer (score 4):

It is a small error.

`arr= (one two three)`

should've been

`arr=(one two three)`

Also you can't use `\n` in `echo`. Use `printf` if you want to use `\n`.

And fixing the rest of the errors, the code looks like this.

```
# array declaration
arr=(one two three)  

# for loop
for (( i=0;i<3;i++ ))
do
    printf "\n $((i+1)) : ${arr[i]}"
done
echo ""
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> arr= (one two three)
> ```

Lets break down what this does.

> ```
> arr=
> ```

This part assigns `$arr` an empty value (temporarily, since it precedes a command).

> ```
> (one two three)
> ```

This part runs `one` in a subshell with arguments `two` and `three`, with the previously assigned value of `$arr`.

Did you perhaps mean to assign the three values to an array in `$arr` instead?